# add more model info to the JWT token

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm creating a messaging app. I have 3 models in my backend Django. I have a profile model that stores user & which room they are connected with(so that every time they log in, their rooms will pop up in side bar like WhatsApp). in profile model I have a many to many relationship with Room model that stores rooms list. As I'm using JWT web token for authentication, I want users profile model/rooms like of that user to be added in the token. so that I can fetch the info from token directly but I don't know how to add that fields info into the token views. I've already customized my token obtain view where I added users name as extra but I need to add the list of rooms too.

Thanks in advance for helping.

```
#model.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Room)

 

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,null=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=False,null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True)
```

```
#views.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        token['name'] = user.username
        **here i want to have a token['room'] that will return me the list of rooms**
  

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

At first get the `Profile`: without reverse relation it can be retrieved via

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Then get the rooms:

```
rooms = profile.rooms.all()
```

At the end you should consider what information about the rooms you are storing into the token. The `name` can be blank and does not need to be unique. So it is better to store the `id`:

```
token['rooms'] = [r.id for r in rooms]
```

Comment: where should i get the profile data? inside the token view? each user has their own list of rooms. i need only the lists of them not all of the rooms

Answer (score 0):

well, i found out by myself. it's very easy. just get all the profile data of that user. now iterate through the list of the rooms using rooms.all()

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['name'] = user.username
        room = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        token['rooms'] = [[r.name,r.id] for r in room.rooms.all()]
        print([r for r in room.rooms.all()])
        # ...

        return token
```